# Search for set/unset bit combination in value C++

Tags: c++, bit

It's my first time working with C++ and I'm tryin to identify if the bits of a given int fall into a specific category:

For each int passed to the function, we implement the rule that every 2 bits represent a singular value within the message, and if that message's value is 2 (10 binary) then we need to return a boolean with false. Examples: (In the column binary representation I separate each 2 bits so its more visible)

| Given value | Binary representation | condition met | Returns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00 00 00 00 | None | true (no condition met) |
| 128 | **10** 00 00 00 | 1st | false |
| 32 | (00) **10** 00 00 | 2nd | false |
| 8 | (00 00) **10** 00 | 3rd | false |
| 2 | (00 00 00) **10** | 4th | false |
| 217 | 11 01 **10** 01 | 3rd | false |
| 153 | **10** 01 **10** 01 | 1st & 3rd | false |

I've found about [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-k-th-bit-set-not/) and tried making a simple function, but it's not working as intended.

```
bool isConditionVoid(int value) {
    bool Condition1 = (value &(1<<8)) && !(value&(1<<7)); 
    bool Condition2 = (value &(1<<6)) && !(value&(1<<5)); 
    bool Condition3 = (value &(1<<4)) && !(value&(1<<3)); 
    bool Condition4 = (value &(1<<2)) && !(value&(1<<1)); 
    if (!Condition1 || !Condition2 || !Condition3 || !Condition4)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Knowing which condition failed could be a plus, but it's not necessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked `1<<2` and `1<<1`? I think that's not what you expect. After you checked these values you will understand the problem.

Comment: @ThomasSablik sorry what do you mean? perhaps I shouldn't be ussing the << operators for those positions?

Comment: The operator is correct but the positions are wrong.

Comment: `1<<1` is `2` not `1`, `1<<8` is `256` (`0b1 0000 0000`) not `128` (`0b1000 0000`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned int condition=((value&0xaaaaaaaa)>>1)&((~value)&0x55555555);
```

This computes a number which has a bit set for each message that is 2. If for example `value=0b11011001`, `value&0xaaaaaaaa` is `0b10001000`, shifting right produces `0b01000100` `~value` is `0b11111111111111111111111100100110`, anding with `0x55555555` produces `0b01010101010101010101010100000100`, and the final and produces `0b100`, showing that condition 3 is met.

Comment: `(value>>1 & ~value) & 0x55555555` saves an operation. Although `value` should be converted to an `unsigned int` first, unless it is known to be nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

First, in C++, int is shorted for signed int, and usually represented by 4 bytes, or 32 bits. So your function only work with the last 8 bits of input integer.

Second, 1<<n means 00 00 00 01 was shift by n bits to the left.

```
1<<8 means (01) 00 00 00 00
1<<7 means      10 00 00 00
```

Which mean all of your bit shift is deviated by 1 position to the left.

Third, the last if statement will return false when any of condition is false, which mean only 10101010 will return true.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++14, you might write the function in intelligible way with binary representation:

```
bool isConditionVoid(std::uint8_t value) {
    bool Condition1 = ((value & 0b00'00'00'11) == 0b00'00'00'10);
    bool Condition2 = ((value & 0b00'00'11'00) == 0b00'00'10'00);
    bool Condition3 = ((value & 0b00'11'00'00) == 0b00'10'00'00);
    bool Condition4 = ((value & 0b11'00'00'00) == 0b10'00'00'00);

    return !Condition1 && !Condition2 && !Condition3 && !Condition4;
}
```